# Unable to get some pages to work with ssl (zpanel)

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, centos

CA certificate installs and works fine, no security issues. I am able to use it for the WordPress admin area and the homepage (root) can be accessed securely no problem. Anytime the server tries to access HTTPS domain.com/anything it returns a 404 page.

I've been teaching myself AWS over the past two weeks and this is the first time I've needed to ask for help. Normally I can find the answers but this time I keep coming up cold. Thanks in advance.

---

Here are the examples:

https://www.pageantsuppliers.com

https://www.pageantsuppliers.com/cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hiring someone on freelancer to figure it out for me. Well worth the $39. Here is what he said so that others can share in the knowledge.

> From roonex  on freelancer:
>
> I edited this file: /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf and on the end of just
> before closing tag  it I added this code:

```
<Directory /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html>
AllowOverride none

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</Directory>
```

> The problem was that for ssl you have to tell the virtual host to use
> same folder for http and https, in plesk or cpanel you have to check
> only one checkbox to do this, but for zpanel you have to do this
> change in the ssl.conf
>
> After this just restart the apache and it will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you have a web server configuration problem.

Long answer: if you save the certificate you get from `$ openssl s_client -connect www.pageantsuppliers.com:443 -CAfile startcom-ca.crt` (just copy/paste it), the end entity (server certificate) looks OK:

```
$ openssl x509 -inform PEM -in pageantsuppliers-com.pem -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 984131 (0xf0443)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=IL, O=StartCom Ltd., OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar  9 18:28:34 2014 GMT
            Not After : Mar 10 07:32:09 2015 GMT
        Subject: description=tq5XRBjgh9USfQ68, C=US, CN=www.pageantsuppliers.com/emailAddress=87f13a43b0ac46298171a954f337671e.protect@whoisguard.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b6:1a:e0:2c:62:cb:74:f6:8a:82:a5:41:85:29:
                    fb:f6:68:7a:a1:68:04:ec:ea:fe:fc:a5:44:66:dc:
                    69:6f:d5:9b:2a:4a:b0:56:00:b9:65:c1:f9:a5:36:
                    f5:66:03:ee:d7:a3:22:7d:a2:eb:45:ba:28:b5:6d:
                    66:29:93:4b:a2:a7:21:d8:ca:fe:4f:43:4f:49:72:
                    10:ee:57:08:d5:27:39:e1:ad:56:9a:7a:24:25:e6:
                    91:6f:b5:8f:32:fb:3e:fc:30:2d:bd:53:7d:3b:d3:
                    f0:b7:a6:1f:eb:60:ea:92:37:5e:d9:da:f5:40:5a:
                    7b:aa:e3:ae:65:60:c0:11:bb:79:4d:08:85:7b:7d:
                    1d:e6:b3:7a:45:91:12:9f:c1:f4:54:9b:9b:a2:a0:
                    f5:e9:64:e2:4f:8f:c6:f3:f4:54:73:02:77:4b:d9:
                    6b:c0:47:84:8f:ea:b4:05:b9:39:0b:1e:f5:37:ee:
                    90:d6:87:e0:c3:15:56:db:e6:fa:b9:fa:4e:1f:36:
                    c8:df:c9:e8:3a:63:46:d2:e9:e6:07:67:00:6a:10:
                    d2:d1:40:19:1a:ac:f5:ef:17:28:73:05:6b:69:d1:
                    74:a8:7b:2e:92:13:fb:f5:d5:d3:57:a6:b6:9f:94:
                    34:68:c2:ff:8f:5a:8c:3b:8e:d5:c4:f7:6a:97:54:
                    a4:97
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Key Agreement
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                DD:18:77:CF:57:39:39:EF:1E:B7:E0:25:09:D2:90:72:83:11:D3:9D
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:EB:42:34:D0:98:B0:AB:9F:F4:1B:6B:08:F7:CC:64:2E:EF:0E:2C:45

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:www.pageantsuppliers.com, DNS:pageantsuppliers.com
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.23223.1.2.3
                  CPS: http://www.startssl.com/policy.pdf
                  User Notice:
                    Organization: StartCom Certification Authority
                    Number: 1
                    Explicit Text: This certificate was issued according to the Class 1 Validation requirements of the StartCom CA policy, reliance only for the intended purpose in compliance of the relying party obligations.

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.startssl.com/crt1-crl.crl

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.startssl.com/sub/class1/server/ca
                CA Issuers - URI:http://aia.startssl.com/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.crt

            X509v3 Issuer Alternative Name: 
                URI:http://www.startssl.com/
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         42:8e:78:33:a0:76:39:90:9c:53:b8:e7:7a:a4:06:6d:8a:7c:
         f4:65:90:87:70:a9:da:b4:19:09:e2:dd:fd:75:39:c8:f8:bf:
         d2:de:e7:0f:70:a8:92:71:2c:fe:45:5f:5b:14:e4:9b:80:1f:
         54:7b:1a:37:b4:de:b7:fc:c8:d4:c6:7f:07:be:cc:16:cb:82:
         08:12:ff:fe:14:cb:ac:64:83:17:a3:a0:f9:e1:97:6f:66:e8:
         9b:13:d3:da:e5:be:c7:43:14:18:6d:bc:76:55:00:c4:8c:8e:
         1e:0f:a1:21:46:e3:60:db:5a:1d:7f:61:49:43:55:d7:b6:1c:
         af:b2:84:f2:e5:e8:f9:e4:db:ab:b6:38:26:74:cb:8d:69:f6:
         9c:0b:ac:fd:bf:9b:c5:3b:3b:2c:16:72:69:7f:7e:7d:7c:37:
         bd:f1:e1:83:5e:42:ed:9c:0e:c3:b5:e1:6d:f3:91:ec:07:ff:
         7d:12:4c:37:73:5d:9f:be:d2:55:8e:ef:c5:48:3d:7d:d5:cb:
         0c:e1:75:ef:dd:0c:8e:46:50:0a:9a:3c:72:28:8d:c0:31:df:
         65:06:44:e0:af:3f:0f:7e:de:04:10:be:a0:e9:b9:c6:03:b8:
         38:fe:b1:a7:fb:af:b7:6f:82:10:7a:a6:38:50:07:9e:5b:19:
         e1:a6:bf:95
```

The issuer is `StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA`, which should be OK. And `StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA`'s issuer is `StartCom Certification Authority`, which should also be OK.

However, when issuing a `GET`:

```
$ echo "GET / HTTP/1.1" | openssl s_client -connect www.pageantsuppliers.com:443 -CAfile ca-bundle.pem -servername www.pageantsuppliers.com
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., CN = StartCom Certification Authority G2
verify return:1
depth=2 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN = StartCom Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN = StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 description = tq5XRBjgh9USfQ68, C = US, CN = www.pageantsuppliers.com, emailAddress = 87f13a43b0ac46298171a954f337671e.protect@whoisguard.com
verify return:1
---
...

    Start Time: 1394991510
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

It appears there is no web server serving content on that port. The `DONE` above should be replaced with raw HTML because `s_client` simply prints what it receives. You can also add `-pause` `-ign_eof` to keep the connection open, but that's not your problem (see [`s_client(1)` docs](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html)).

You have a web server configuration problem.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. Sadly, that is exactly where I am stuck. I feel like the solution is right under my nose but I cannot see it. I have edited the ssl.conf and .htaccess to the best of my googling but I just keep making it worse. Then having to restore another AWS AMI, at least I have that :)